# std:string::substr is exception safe?

Tags: c++, string, exception, erase

I wrote some code where I use `substr` from `std::string`.

According to [this C++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/):

> If *pos* is greater than the string length, an out_of_range exception is thrown.

As I already checked, if I execute this function with following parameters:

1. I execute function: `test.substr(0,test.size()-2);`
2. `std::string test = {"ABC"}; result: test == "A"`
3. `std::string test = {"AB"};  result: test == ""`
4. `std::string test = {"A"};   result: test == "A"`
5. `std::string test = {""};    result: test == ""`

My conclusions are:

1. If original string size is higher or equal 2 function works straight-forward.
2. In case when original string size is smaller than 2 no exceptions are thrown, but function is returning original string.

My question:

Is it safe to leave it as `test.substr(0,test.size()-2);` without checking its size before?

Comment: When you do `test.substr(0,test.size()-2)` it shouldn't change `test` (No side effects, so by definition exception safe)

Comment: It depends on whether `test.size()` is guaranteed to return an unsigned value.

Comment: @Eljay It's guaranteed to be unsigned. In future, it seems `ssize()` will be added to return a signed size. `size()` will remain unsigned.

Comment: @Eljay As in `test.size()-2` is an unsigned integer undeflow and test.substr(0, 18446744073709551615) will return the whole string.

Comment: I think you're confusing the two arguments. `pos` is the *first* parameter, for which you always pass zero. This can never be less than the length of the string. None of your calls will result in an exception.

Comment: As a point of terminology, "exception safe" means the method *always* leaves the object in a valid state, even if it throws an exception. You are asking "does this method throw for this input"

Answer (score 4):

This is completely safe.  It is only the first parameter that matters if an exception is thrown (besides a `bad_alloc` for running out of memory but you have other problems then).

The first parameter must be in `[0, size()]`.  Since you use `0`, and `0` is always in `[0, size()]`, you'll never throw a `std::out_of_range` exception.

What happens if the second parameter is greater than the sub string size could be is that you just get the full sub string.  So `test.substr(0,test.size()-2);` for `std::string test = {""}` will always result in `""` since `test.size()-2` is a really big number (unsigned underflow).

Comment: It should be noted that since `size_type` is unsigned, `size() - 2` on a string with size smaller then 2 will result in unsigned undeflow, which is fine but means you'll get the whole string due to the result being near the maximum value of an unsigned.

Comment: @NikosC. Sounds good. Comments cleaned up and answer updated a little.

Answer (score 2):

The function throws an exception when `pos > size()`
As in your examples the parameter `pos` is always equal to 0 then the function is safe. That is the `pos` never can be greater than the value of `size()`.

Take into account that the second parameter is defined like

```
basic_string substr(size_type pos = 0, size_type n = npos) const;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and the function (C++ Standard ) behaves like

> 2 Effects: Determines the effective length rlen of the string to copy
>   as the smaller of n and size() - pos.

For this expression

```
test.size()-2
```

that has an unsigned integer type when `size()` is less than 2 when you have a big unsigned value (due to the usual arithmetic conversions). For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s;

    auto n = s.size() - 2;
    std::cout << n << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

the program output is

```
18446744073709551614
```

So the function selects the value of the member function `size()`.

This situation is demonstrated by these two examples

```
4)std::string test = {"A"};   result: test == "A"

5)std::string test = {""};    result: test == ""
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is safe, but not for reasons you think it is.**

First things first: `std::string::substr` is not fully exception safe, it will throw if `pos` (i.e. first argument) is greater than `size()`.

Secondly, both arguments to `substr` are of type `std::string::size_type`, which is by default an unsigned integral type.
Because it is unsigned, underflow is well-defined, so `0 - 2` is going to result in `std::numeric_limits<std::string::size_type>::max() - 1`.
There is no upper bound on second argument to `substr()`, so it is safe to call it with as high value as you wish (in fact, default argument is likely `std::numeric_limits<std::string::size_type>::max()`).

So, what happens when you call `substr(0, negative_value)` is you ask "give me substring from index `0` to `huge_number`", which in probably all cases will return you the whole string.